# NServiceBus information

Tags: nservicebus

Can somebody tell me where I can read about NSerivceBus for introductory information ?(What is it? Why use, etc...)

Is this to just send messages between two systems or, can you also send data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for an elevator pitch for NServiceBus, I would say:

> NServiceBus is a messaging
>   infrastructure which allows you to
>   increase scalability, reliability, and
>   maintainability in your distributed
>   applications.

Here is a short list of resources:

- [The NServiceBus Website](http://particular.net/nservicebus), of course

  - [The documentation pages](http://docs.particular.net/)
- [Udi Dahan's Blog](http://www.udidahan.com/?blog=true)
- [Andreas Öhlund's Blog](http://andreasohlund.net/)
- [Jonathan Oliver's Blog](http://jonathan-oliver.blogspot.com/)

Articles relating specifically to what is, and more importantly, why bother learning it:

- [Stop Losing Data in Production](http://www.nservicebus.com/StopLosingData.aspx)
- [My NserviceBus Moment of Bliss](http://www.make-awesome.com/2011/02/my-nservicebus-moment-of-bliss/)
- [Message Based Architecture Goodness](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/message-based-architecture-goodness/)

I'm marking this answer as community wiki so that others can contribute more links.